# Broadcast variable using parfor

Tags: matlab, parfor

I am now trying to do parallel computing in Matlab and want to use parfor loop to improve the efficiency. The problem is I can guarantee that each loop is independent with each other but I finally need to update a global variable (maybe called broadcast variable in Matlab), when I want to assign some value to it there is a problem says it can't be classified. If I still want to do it in this Matlab, how can I solve this problem or is there any other way I can try to improve the efficiency?

The code is like this:

```
Atoms(1:nOfAtomsInTwoDim,:)=TwoDimAtoms;
odd_type=TwoDimAtoms;
even_type=TwoDimAtoms;
even_type(:,1)=TwoDimAtoms(:,1)+LatticeSpacing/2;
even_type(:,2)=TwoDimAtoms(:,2)+LatticeSpacing/2;
parfor i=2:1:nOflayers+1
    temp_type=TwoDimAtoms;
    if mod(i,2)
        temp_type=odd_type;
        temp_type(:,3)=TwoDimAtoms(:,3)+(i-1)*LatticeSpacing/2;
    else
        temp_type=even_type;
        temp_type(:,3)=TwoDimAtoms(:,3)+(i-1)*LatticeSpacing/2;
    end
    iBegin=(i-1)*nOfAtomsInTwoDim+1;
    iEnd=i*nOfAtomsInTwoDim;
    Atoms(iBegin,iEnd,:)=temp_type;
end
```

Comment: There is a typo on the last line, is that the problem? `Atoms(iBegin,iEnd,:)` should be `Atoms(iBegin:iEnd,:)` (the first `,` should be `:`)

Comment: Which one is your global variable? It is hard to understand what your problem is without a code example that we can run.

Comment: PetrH you're correct, I am not super familiar with Matlab actually... But I think it still doesn't work after I change it:(

Comment: David, the global is Atoms which is a n by 3 matrix.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't executable which makes it slightly tricky to work out what's going on, and as @PetrH points out I assume your indexing expression at the end is intended to be `Atoms(iBegin:iEnd,:)`.

To make this work in `parfor`, you need to arrange for `Atoms` to be [sliced](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/sliced-variables.html) (*broadcast* variables are inputs to the `parfor` loop which are constant and the same for each iteration). In other words, your indexing expression needs to be something more like

```
parfor i = ...
  ...
  Atoms(i, :) = ...;
end
```

Having said all that, if this is your entire `parfor` loop, I would concentrate instead on vectorising things rather than applying `parfor`. It appears that the amount of work inside the `parfor` loop is rather small and it is unlikely to give you much benefit, whereas my guess is that vectorisation should give you much better speedup.

Comment: Thanks Edric. I am wrong with Atoms(iBegin:iEnd,:), as you said, if Atoms is a broadcast variable, then I am not allowed to assign value to it in parfor right? If I really want to assign value to a global variable what should I do? And can you explain in which way can I use vector to speed up?

Comment: I am sorry *vectorisation.